# Meaning of "to be Accounts Receivable for someone"

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, semantics

I understand what accounts receivable are, and I understand what factoring is. But I don't understand what the phrase "to be accounts receivable for someone" means, e.g. "I'm accounts receivable for company X".

Does it mean I owe company X money, or does it mean that I'm collecting the money other people owe to company X for them? Or something else?

Comment: It means you represent (i.e. *are*) the Accounts Receivable Department for Company X.  You send out invoices and cash checks for Company X.

Answer (score 3):

This means that you perform the Accounts Receivable functions for the company.

This could mean that either:

- you are employed by the company as a salaried full-time employee, and are the only one doing this job (otherwise you would likely say "I work in Accounts Receivable for XYZ company" , if there was more than one full-time employee in the *department*)
- or, quite possibly, that you are performing Accounts Receivables as a service, and charging/being paid as a separate entity /independent contractor/ company for those services.  Furthermore, you could be paid:

  - on an hourly basis
  - per invoice
  - by the number of accounts
  - per total $$ dollar volume / a percentage of $$ billed
  - a flat monthly recurring subscription / fee for your services